# cmd/cntrl + a doesnt work on jQuery limit function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a jQuery input box character limiter with count but when I try <kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> (highlight/select all) doesn't work in the input box it flashes for a second and then disappears. Not sure why this is happening. [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amayp0oa/1/)

Here is my jQuery:

```
var maxchars = 10;
$('#post_text').keyup(function () {
    var tlength = $(this).val().length;
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxchars));
    var tlength = $(this).val().length;
    remain = maxchars - parseInt(tlength);
    $('#remain').text(remain);
});
```

and the html:

```
<span id="remain">10</span> characters remaining
<br />
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg auto-size"
    placeholder="What would you like to post?"
    name="post_text" id="post_text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `keyup(...)` with `bind('input',...)`:

```
var maxchars = 10;
$('#post_text').bind('input',function () {
    var tlength = $(this).val().length;
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxchars));
    var tlength = $(this).val().length;
    remain = maxchars - parseInt(tlength);
    $('#remain').text(remain);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bind( ) fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it does work (Firefox 40.0.3.) However, it may be not working with some other browsers. Most probably, it has something to do with the keyup function.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a check for the char you're pressing. Char code for 'Ctrl' key is 17 and the below code uses a flag to say if 'ctrl' is pressed then don't check the input length. Let me know if this works for you.

```
var maxchars = 10;
$('#post_text').keydown(function (e) {
    var checkInput = true;
    if (e.which == 17) {
        checkInput = false;   
    }
    if (checkInput){
        var tlength = $(this).val().length;
        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxchars));
        var tlength = $(this).val().length;
        remain = maxchars - parseInt(tlength);
        $('#remain').text(remain);
    }
});
```

------------- EDIT --------------

What I would be inclined to do is actually to add a maxlen attribute to the input tag as so maxlen="10" and then you don't have to do the check for input length, but only to update the label for input - '10 characters remaining'